# Remove an item from ienumerable<string>

Tags: c#, string, ienumerable

I have a method that expect `IEnumerable<string>` as you can see here :

```
  public static string FromDecimalAscii(IEnumerable<string> input)
        {

            return new string(input.Select(s => (char)int.Parse(s)).ToArray());
        }
```

But every time the last record of my IEnumerable is  empty so i got an error in this line because of that :

```
    return new string(input.Select(s => (char)int.Parse(s)).ToArray());
```

So i have to remove that item from my `IEnumerable` .

The  error:`Input string was not in a correct format`
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: What is the _error_ exactly?

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: I said dear friend because my last item is empty string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need just to filter collection with `Where`:

```
return new string(input.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                       .Select(s => (char)int.Parse(s)).ToArray());
```

You can also use extension method to use `TryParse`:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public delegate bool TryParseDelegate<TSource>(string s, out TSource source);

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> WhereParsed<TSource, TResult>(
                                               this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                               TryParseDelegate<TResult> tryParse)
    {

         // TODO: check arguments against null first

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            TResult result;
            if (tryParse(item != null ? item.ToString() : null, out result))
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var collection = input.WhereParsed<string, int>(int.TryParse)
                      .Cast<char>()
                      .ToArray();
return new string(collection);
```